# react native measure not working on custom class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component, measure

I have a class component which contains a custom button like so:
(please be aware this is simplified version of the actual component)

```
class CustomerMainView extends Component<CustomerMainViewProps> {

    private qr_btn_loc: LayoutRectangle;
    private btn_ref: RefObject<ImageButton>;

    constructor(props: CustomerMainViewProps) {
        super(props);

        this.qr_btn_loc = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 };
        this.btn_ref = createRef<ImageButton>();

     

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <View style={this.props.style}>
                <ImageButton
                    ref={this.btn_ref}
                    style={style.button}
                    image={require("./qr.png")}
                    onLayout={(l: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
                        this.btn_ref.current?.measureInWindow((x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) => {
                            this.qr_btn_loc = {x, y, width, height};
                    }}
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log(this.qr_btn_loc);
                    }}
                ></ImageButton>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The custom button components looks like the following:

```
interface ImageButtonProps extends TouchableHighlightProps {
    image: ImageSourcePropType;
}

class ImageButton extends Component<ImageButtonProps> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight {...this.props}>
                <Image style={style.img} source={this.props.image}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}
```

In the `CustomerMainView` component i try to get the position of the `ImageButton` component relative to the window with the help of the `measureInWindow` function from its `ref`. But I keep getting the following error:

> Property 'measureInWindow' does not exist on type 'ImageButton'.

If I replace `ImageButton` with a standard react native component like `View` or `TouchableHighlight` it works just fine...

What am i doing wrong and how do I make it work on a custom component like `ImageButton`?